# How to remove title and icon from SharePoint Chrome Control

Tags: c#, sharepoint

In a SharePoint MVC App, i am using the following code for chrome Control.

```
<!-- Chrome control placeholder Options are declared inline.  -->
        <div
            id="chrome_ctrl_container"
            data-ms-control="SP.UI.Controls.Navigation"
            title="Title of the application"
            data-ms-options='{  

            "appIconUrl" : "Images/Logo.GIF",
            "appTitle" : "SharePoint MVC", 
            "appHelpPageUrl" : "Help.html",
            "settingsLinks" : [
                {
                    "linkUrl" : "Account.html",
                    "displayName" : "Account settings"
                },
                {
                    "linkUrl" : "Contact.html",
                    "displayName" : "Contact us"
                }
            ]
         }'>
        </div>
```

I want to remove the Title and Site Icon so i can create a custom header after sharepoint bar.

[image: Image for detail]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options depending on how much you want to remove:

1. Adjust the options in the `data-ms-options` attribute.
2. You can also remove the `data-ms-control` as well. This will remove the navigation, and you can substitute whatever you'd like for it.
3. You can create the client chrome control in javascript instead of declaring it.

ref: [How to: Use the client chrome control in apps for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179916.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following option:

**"bottomHeaderVisible": false,**

For example, your code would be:

```
<!-- Chrome control placeholder Options are declared inline.  -->
        <div
            id="chrome_ctrl_container"
            data-ms-control="SP.UI.Controls.Navigation"
            title="Title of the application"
            data-ms-options='{  
            "bottomHeaderVisible": false,
            "appIconUrl" : "Images/Logo.GIF",
            "appTitle" : "SharePoint MVC", 
            "appHelpPageUrl" : "Help.html",
            "settingsLinks" : [
                {
                    "linkUrl" : "Account.html",
                    "displayName" : "Account settings"
                },
                {
                    "linkUrl" : "Contact.html",
                    "displayName" : "Contact us"
                }
            ]
         }'>
        </div>
```